# g++のコンパイルエラー：error : declaration of '~~~' changes meaning of '~~~'

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

現在、「ゼロからのOS自作入門」という書籍で学習している者です。
環境はUbuntu 20.04.2、g++9.3.0で挑戦しております。

現在、筆者の用意したドライバを用いて、USBデバイスをコントロールするという章です。(購読されている方は、第6章です)
ここで、用意されたドライバを含めたプログラムをビルドすると、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
./usb/xhci/trb.hpp:325:25: error: declaration of 'usb::EndpointID usb::xhci::StopEndpointCommandTRB::EndpointID() const' changes meaning of 'EndpointID' [-fpermissive]
./usb/endpoint.hpp:13:12: note: 'EndpointID' declared here as 'class usb::EndpointID'
```

ソースコードの該当部分は以下の通りとなります。
./usb/xhci/trb.hpp

```
...
namespace usb::xhci {
...
  union StopEndpointCommandTRB {
  ...
    EndpointID EndpointID() const {
      return ...
    }
  };
}
```

./usb/endpoint.hpp

```
...
namespace usb {
...
  class EndpointID {
    ...
  };
}
```

自分で調べた限り、どうやらclang++やVC++ではエラーにならないらしいということと、g++でも解決方法があるとのことですが、英語サイトだっため、よく理解できませんでした。一応英語サイトを見て試したことは、
・名前空間を明らかにしたほうが良さそうなので、戻り値の型にusb::を明示する
　→　上記とほぼ同様のエラーが出る。
・class EndpointIDを、structに直して、戻り値の型にstructを明示する
　→　上記と同様。
解決法お分かりの方は、何卒ご教授いただければ幸いです。

また、私としては、単純に関数の名前をクラス型名と違うユニークなものにすればこのような問題はそもそも起こらないように思うのですが、あえてこのような実装をする場合、どのような意味があるのでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通り、`g++` にオプションスイッチ [`-fpermissive`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fpermissive) を追加することで回避する事ができます(error が warning level になります)。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり、-fpermissiveを追加すると、warningは出るものの、エラーを回避できました。しかし、なぜerror乃至warningが出るのかは謎のままです。

Comment: 個人的には、このようなケースでクラス名と関数名を合わせる理由はありません(関数名にgetを付けます)。可能であれば[書籍の執筆者のリポジトリ](https://github.com/uchan-nos)のIssue、またはtwitterで意図を問い合わせてみるのはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @udaken やはりそうですよね…自分でこのあたり回避できるように手を尽くしたのですが、コード量の多さに加えて謎のエラーが連発で手に負えなかったので、ひとまずはオプションで回避することにしました。機を見て作者のリポジトリのIssueやTwitterへの問い合わせもしてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 名前空間を明らかにしたほうが良さそうなので、戻り値の型にusb::を明示する

で問題無いと思います。

[戻り値に名前空間の指定していない再現コード](https://wandbox.org/permlink/42tg7cDfNf5XZpXU)に`usb::`を追加して戻り値に名前空間の指定をすれば、[エラーは発生しません](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lgIHPrzotbo0WGOz)。

> 上記とほぼ同様のエラーが出る。

とのことですが、他に`EndpointID`と記述した箇所で`usb::`の追加(もしくは`StopEndpointCommandTRB::`の指定)が漏れているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。様々見直したのですが、やはりusb::を加えたのみでは、エラーを回避することはできませんでした。usb::を加える前後で変化するのは、エラーメッセージの赤いアンダーラインの位置だけです。加える前は戻り値の下ですが、加えると今度は関数名の下にアンダーラインが出ます。メッセージは全く変わりません。

Comment: @tayu どうやら`StopEndpointCommandTRB`のコンストラクタがあるとエラーが再現するようです。残念ながら私にはエラーになる理由がわかりませんでした。
元のコードはApache License 2.0なのでコード片を公開することは問題ないと思います。他の方が回答しやすいように[再現コード](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sA3TkOw4OYWHWvr2)も元の質問に追記したほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: 丁寧なコメントありがとうございます。
ひとまずは-fpermissiveで回避することができたので、先に読み進めることにしました。なぜclangでは特別にオプション無しで回避できるのか、問題の根源はどこなのか、謎は尽きないですが、一旦パスして、あとで振り返ろうと思います。ありがとうございました。